# Yield single values from map of iterable

Tags: python, iterator

I have a function that maps elements of an iterable to another iterable. I then want to get single items out of the flattened version of this object. The following code models what I want:

```
a = [1, 2 ,3 , 4]
b = map(lambda x:(x, x), a)
c = itertools.chain(*b)
# next(c) returns `1`, `1`, `2`, etc
```

However, if `a` is very large or the values produced by my `map` are large, I don't want to try to hold the whole list in memory. Is there a way to do this on the fly so that I am not storing/precomputing as much.

Comment: maybe create normal function with `yield` instead of using `map`. But maybe problem can be chain which may need all values to flatten it and you may have to flatten it directly in function which use `yield` - in your example you can use two `yield x`  to flatten it.

Comment: `map` return an iterator that applies function to every item of iterable, yielding the results. 
`itertools.chain` make an iterator that returns elements from the first iterable until it is exhausted, then proceeds to the next iterable, until all of the iterables are exhausted.
It is already there as your statements, not occupy more in you memory.

Comment: The `*` expands `b`, so it evaluates everything at that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chain includes a function for lazy unpacking: `itertools.chain.from_iterable`. In the example given:

```
a = [1, 2 ,3 , 4]
b = map(lambda x:(x, x), a)
c = itertools.chain.from_iterable(b)
# next(c) returns `1`, `1`, `2`, etc
```